# The output of the code after compiling in CodeBlocks is 19,9.Can someone please help me how its executing?.The answer i got is 20,9

Tags: c, codeblocks, decrement

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int a=4,b=5;
    b=a+++a--;
    a=++b+b--;
    printf("%d,%d",a,b);
    return 0;
}
```

Please explain the output of the above code.

Comment: These two lines `b=a++ + a--;` and  `a= ++b+b--;` cause undefined behavior. Do not use such constructs.

Comment: @DNT sorry? Whats the issue

Comment: @RamolaSingh See the linked duplicate.

Comment: Sorry,I'm new to this.And couldn't figure out the solution of the code.Can you still help?

Comment: Do your additions and subtractions separately, not all on the same statement. This way you make it clear what your intent is, and there will be no UB.

Comment: @dbush That dupe is only half the truth though, the `a+++` thing is related to the "maximum munch" rule. I added a second dupe link.

Comment: @Lundin Looks like that was added after the question was closed.

Comment: @dbush Yep, if you got a gold C badge you can edit the dupe target list and add/remove links.